# What in this CSS is causing this difference in font thickness?

Tags: css, fonts

I have two bits of text. One is in a paragraph element, the other is text for a submit button input.

[image]

[image]

Why is the font slightly thicker in the button?

[image]

Paragraph CSS (taken from Computed Style in Chrome Developer Tools)

```
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
display: block;
float: left;
font-family: 'Din Text Pro Regular', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
height: 24px;
line-height: 24px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 16px;
margin-top: 11.199999809265137px;
width: 119px;
```

Input CSS (taken from Computed Style in Chrome Developer Tools)

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-border-image: none;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65098) 0px 1px 3px 0px, rgba(97, 232, 203, 0.701961) 0px 1px 0px 0px inset;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
-webkit-user-select: text;
-webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(75, 208, 179), rgb(38, 174, 144));
border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
border-top-style: none;
border-top-width: 0px;
box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65098) 0px 1px 3px 0px, rgba(97, 232, 203, 0.701961) 0px 1px 0px 0px inset;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Din Text Pro Regular', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
height: 41px;
letter-spacing: normal;
line-height: 16px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-top: 11px;
text-align: center;
text-indent: 0px;
text-shadow: rgba(24, 97, 81, 0.34902) 0px 1px 0px;
text-transform: none;
vertical-align: baseline;
white-space: pre;
width: 159px;
word-spacing: 0px;
writing-mode: lr-tb;
```

Comment: I believe buttons default on some browsers to bold ... try applying font-weight:normal; to the input.

Comment: My bet is on the- text-shadow: rgba(24, 97, 81, 0.34902) 0px 1px 0px; Can you post a link to this page? Also I recommend firebug for firefox as a great tool for similar problems.

Comment: Is the font-family Din Text Pro Regular for the button as well?

Comment: Are the fonts loaded correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to put this at the top of my CSS. It seems to do the trick, at least so far:

```
button {
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Chrome as some kind of bug, in which it displays the fonts thicker depending on the brightness of its color.

More info here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=163369

**Edit: Found more related info and fix**

Actually, it is a [known](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=163369) [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142584):

I was able to fix this by following [this article](http://tanookilabs.com/your-fonts-look-bad-in-chrome-heres-the-fix/).

Kinda late, but it may still be usefull to some.